# Partition unaccessable - I/O error

Tags: partition, badblocks

In my laptop I have one drive that has been split in several partitions:

- *sda1* swap
- *sda2* vfat
- *sda3* ext4 (home + root)
- *sda5* ntfs (just for  files)

One day I wanted to move folder from *sda5* to *sda1* (i know - bad idea to move, not copy and detele later). Process was interrupted and files went missing (not copied to new place and not accessable in old place either) and I did not catched error message. As in result, i can no longer access *sda5* drive.

(Maybe) usefull information - before Ubuntu I had Windows10 and *sda5* partition was used the same way for file storage + *OneDrive* sycn folder was located there. Partition was not formated, when I migrated to Ubuntu. Now (in Ubuntu) folder *OneDrive* was just a folder name, without any sync added to it.

Now everytime I try to browse *sda5* partition, I get error:

```
This location could not be displayed.
Sorry, could not display all the contents of “Files”: Error when getting information for file '/media/vilerts/Files/OneDriveTemp': Input/output error
```

I did check for badblocks:

```
sudo badblocks -svn -b 512 -c 65536 /dev/sda5
```

After 8-9h I got results:

```
Testing with random patern: 53364352 done, 20:14 elapsed, (0/0/0 errors).
53364353
..
53364479
100.00% done, 8:24:83 elapsed (0/0/128 errors)
```

I tried to format these sectors with following command for each sector:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda5 bs=1024 count=1 seek=53364353
..
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda5 bs=1024 count=1 seek=53364477
```

After that I checked for badblocks again and nothing was found (no badblocks?). But it did not helped - everything stayed the same. I have a feeling, that most things I have done was compleatly unecessary for thi situation, so I am kind a stuck.

**Update:**  Question - how to get *sda5* partition back in working state with all files and folder?

**Update 2** - this set of logs occurs multi times in syslog files when searching *sda*.

```
Sep 18 01:04:04 Vilerts ntfs-3g[4949]: Version 2013.1.13AR.1 external FUSE 29
Sep 18 01:04:04 Vilerts ntfs-3g[4949]: Mounted /dev/sda5 (Read-Write, label "Files", NTFS 3.1)
Sep 18 01:04:04 Vilerts ntfs-3g[4949]: Cmdline options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177
Sep 18 01:04:04 Vilerts ntfs-3g[4949]: Mount options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sda5,blkdev,blksize=4096
Sep 18 01:04:04 Vilerts ntfs-3g[4949]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Sep 18 01:04:04 Vilerts udisksd[2211]: Mounted /dev/sda5 at /media/vilerts/Files on behalf of uid 1000
Sep 18 01:04:06 Vilerts udisksd[2211]: Cleaning up mount point /media/vilerts/Files (device 8:5 is not mounted)
Sep 18 01:04:06 Vilerts ntfs-3g[4949]: Unmounting /dev/sda5 (Files)
Sep 18 01:04:06 Vilerts udisksd[2211]: Unmounted /dev/sda5 on behalf of uid 1000
```

Comment: Looks like your disk is dying. If you have backups, get a new disk and restore the backups on it. If you don't have backups, you *may* be able to get some of your data back. Look at the kernel logs in `/var/log/syslog`, what do they say about `sda`?

Comment: Log information is added to post as *Update 2*. I found out, that I can get to other files and folders by terminal - I will copy them to external HDD and format partition. Or maybe I should do something else with partition? And - how safe is to use it again (after formating)?